# AWS CodeDeploy shuts nodejs server down after script times out

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, continuous-integration, aws-code-deploy

I have been scratching my head over this for past few hours.

**Issue summary**

CodeDeploy runs through all the lifecycle hooks and in the ApplicationStart hook, it starts my server successfully and waits until timeout of 60s and then shuts it down.

And the deployment fails...

**Long Story:**

I created a simple NodeJS server which returns `{version:1.0.0}` on port 4000.

Wrote an appspec.yml file:

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: "/home/ec2-user/my-app"
hooks:
  AfterInstall:
    - location: "scripts/install_dependencies.sh"
      timeout: 300
      runas: ec2-user

  ApplicationStart:
    - location: "scripts/start_server.sh"
      timeout: 60
      runas: ec2-user
```

Zipped it up and pushed to a bucket in S3.

Started a standalone EC2 linux instance with NodeJS installed (without auto scaling).

Then initiated a deployment from CodeDeploy as an in-place deployment.

All is well in the process, until ApplicationStart hook where it boots the server and shuts it down after 60s and throws an error of script time out (which is all fair).

> **But how am I suppose to keep my deployment from failing and how to keep nodejs server running??**

PS. here is the start script just in case:

```
source /home/ec2-user/.bash_profile
cd /home/ec2-user/my-app/
npm start
```

Comment: Try looking in both the codedeploy logs and the syslogs on the server itself.

Comment: if `npm start` is blocking (it does not go into background or daemon mode) your script will keep running `npm start` for 60 seconds and then it will timeout.  Thus better to make it run as daemon anyway, so that it restarts after instance reboots, stops and starts.

Comment: Thanks @marcin, I will try using pm2